# Empty Text Filter Shows No Data

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've created a Text Filter to filter a Data View Web Part based on the document name. The filter itself works great, but when the filter is empty, there are no results returned.

Does anyone know of a workaround? I'm not very good with XSL, so any of the solutions I've seen either don't work for me or I don't understand.

Paste of the code - http://pastebin.com/zB76Hbze

Thanks!

Comment: What you expect? If there is no any empty document name, it will return 0 result.

Comment: @VirajGorajia well I was hoping that if the filter was empty, it would show all documents